# Compiling Error Java

Tags: java

So i have been working on my Project1 and For some reason i cant figure out why It wont run. I get the Error "Could not find the main class". What am i doing wrong?

My code is:
https://gist.github.com/anonymous/6604f427cc9d17391478

I'm not sure how to post all the code properly with out making it super confusing (I tried to figure it out earlier) But let me know if i can help!

Is there something wrong with my code? Or do i need to compile it in a certain way?

Comment: possible duplicate of [What does "Could not find or load main class" mean?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18093928/what-does-could-not-find-or-load-main-class-mean)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if your using eclipse, goto to run configurations, select:
Project: my Project1 
Main Class: assignment1.Assignment1_test

this will work for sure :)

Comment: Another way is to make sure the file containing `main` is open in the editor, then *Run As -> Java Application* (Or press Alt+Shift+X then press J).

Answer (score 1):

[image]

Let's say you have a folder/package `assignment1` somewhere on your file system inside which you have your `Assignment1_test` and `Fraction` class.Refer the screenshot above to compile and run your code. :)

Answer (score 0):

You have it in a package named `assignment1`. This means it is in a folder named `assignment1`. After compiling, go up to the folder that contains `assignment1` then run `java assignment1.Assignment1_test` from there.

`java` expects a fully-qualified class name (the name of the class including the package). It also expects that the class is in your classpath (`.` is implicitly added). Packages are tied directly to the directory structure.

Combining that all together, since the full-qualified name `assignment1.Assigment1_test` must be specified to `java`, and since the package structure is the directory structure, then the class is expected to be in `assignment1\` relative to the current directory and therefore you *must* be in the directory that contains `assignment1` to execute it (unless it is somewhere else in your classpath, which, given your situation, I'm guessing is not the case).